# iODBC - odbc.ini not showing in System DNS and iODBC admin crashes when adding a manual DNS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, iodbc

I'm trying to setup Snowflake on a Mac. When trying to the DNS settings within iODBC, the odbc.ini file is not picked up automatically by iODBC data source admin. When I try to add the DNS manually, iODBC crashes. I have the most recent iODBC installation, as well as the most recent Snowflake drivers. I can post the iODBC crash log if needed. Thanks!

Install Snowflake drivers and add DNS into iODBC data source administrator. Wanting to pull a pivot table into Excel.

Comment: Have you installed the right ODBC for your platform? MAC M1 or Intel?

Comment: I believe so, downloaded from here - https://developers.snowflake.com/odbc/

Comment: There are 2 versions there: `macaarch64` for M1 and `mac64` for Intel. If you check your Mac-> `About This Mac` do you see an `Core Intel Core i<3/5/79>` processor or M1?

Comment: It's using i7. I've downloaded the mac64 version from this link https://developers.snowflake.com/odbc/

Comment: Add the log then, as that might help.

Comment: It's saying that x86_64h is required.

Comment: [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen(/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64h')),

Comment: Can you run this in a terminal and show the output: `file /opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib`

Comment: robben@admins-MacBook-Pro-4 ~ % file /opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib
/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [i386:Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386] [x86_64]
/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
robben@admins-MacBook-Pro-4 ~ %

Comment: That looks ok, can you try following the steps from [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-create-Snowflake-ODBC-DSN-On-MacOS) and see if you still have the issue?